# Assignment or increment operator in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, operators

I have been running this code at different compilers. At Microsft VS. it prints 1, but at gcc, it prints 0. What is the result according to the standard c++. I don't if there is standardization for this piece of code as well.

```
int a=0;
a=a++;
cout << a<< endl;
```

Comment: This will answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points

Comment: The C++ tag wiki *explicitly* tells you not to ask this.

Answer (score 2):

`a=a++` is [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). Not only is there no standard definition for what will happen, it isn't even guaranteed to always do the same thing between different runs.

It could print 0 now, 1 the next time, and crash your program on the third attempt.